# Make something appear only on first page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

How can I make a banner only appear on the index page of my wordpress theme but when the click to the second or any other page from the pagination of recent posts I do not want this to appear.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the conditional [`is_paged()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged)

```
if( !is_paged() ) {
    // Show what you wanna show
}
```

It's only going to show on the first page, on page 2, 3, 4... it's not going to show.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below condition...

```
if(is_home() || is_front_page()) {
    // Write your code which you want to display on home page only
}
```